# With Python 3 and lxml, how to extract the Version number from a SOAP WSDL?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, lxml

When I test with a subset of the WSDL file, with Name Spaces omitted from the file and code, it works fine.

```
#  for reference, these are the final lines from the WSDL
#
#   <wsdl:service name="Shopping">
#           <wsdl:documentation>
#               <Version>1027</Version>
#           </wsdl:documentation>
#       <wsdl:port binding="ns:ShoppingBinding" name="Shopping">
#           <wsdlsoap:address location="http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping"/>
#       </wsdl:port>
#   </wsdl:service>
#</wsdl:definitions>

from lxml import etree
wsdl = etree.parse('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ShoppingService.wsdl')
print(wsdl.findtext('wsdl:.//Version'))   # wish this would print 1027

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 "/Users/matecsaj/Google Drive/Projects/collectibles/eBay/figure-it3.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 79, in lxml._elementpath.xpath_tokenizer (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:2414)
    KeyError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/matecsaj/Google Drive/Projects/collectibles/eBay/figure-it3.py", line 14, in <module>
print(wsdl.findtext('wsdl:.//Version'))   # wish this would print 1027
File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2230, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.findtext (src/lxml/etree.c:69049)
File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1552, in lxml.etree._Element.findtext (src/lxml/etree.c:60629)
File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 329, in lxml._elementpath.findtext (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:10089)
File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 311, in lxml._elementpath.find (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:9610)
File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 300, in lxml._elementpath.iterfind (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:9282)
File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 277, in lxml._elementpath._build_path_iterator (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:8675)
File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 82, in xpath_tokenizer (src/lxml/_elementpath.c:2542)
SyntaxError: prefix 'wsdl' not found in prefix map

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you actually registered the `wsdl` namespace in the namespace map thingy that I forget the name of? (Otherwise, you have to use the full name, not just the mapped name.) Also, can you really do searches like `wsdl:.//Version` and expect the namespace to be attached to each subpath rather than explicitly specifying `wsdl:Version`? (Forgive me if this part is stupid; it's been a while since dealt with XML with namespaces…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to the kind folks that commented, here is a modified solution that does print the Version number. All I could get working was the wildcard search. Also, the iterator skipped the Version element, so I had to get at it from its parent element. Good enough.

```
from lxml import etree
wsdlLink = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
wsdl = etree.parse('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ShoppingService.wsdl')
for element in wsdl.iter('{'+wsdlLink+'}*'):
    if 'documentation' in element.tag:
        for child in element:
            print(child.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The xml has namespaces defined in it, hence to access the element you need to define the link of the namespace. Please see if the code below helps:

```
wsdlLink = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
wsdl = etree.parse('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ShoppingService.wsdl')
print(wsdl.findtext('{'+wsdlLink+'}//Version'))
```